# Project Euler Attack #2

Tags: c#, programming-challenge

This is my implementation of [Project Euler #2](https://projecteuler.net/problem=2) in C#.  It takes 0 milliseconds to run, and I believe it is correct - I have seen nothing to indicate otherwise!

> By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.

```
static void GetFibos(ref List<int> nums, int maxVal)
{
    nums.Add(1);
    int lastNum = 2;

    while (lastNum <= maxVal)
    {
        nums.Add(lastNum);
        lastNum = nums[nums.Count - 2] + nums[nums.Count - 1];
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
    s.Start();

    List<int> fiboNums = new List<int>();
    GetFibos(ref fiboNums, 4000000);

    int sumEvenFibos = 0;

    foreach (int i in fiboNums) { if (i % 2 == 0) sumEvenFibos += i; }

    s.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine(sumEvenFibos);
    Console.WriteLine(s.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

Is there anything I should be doing different?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why do you need the actual list of Fibonacci numbers? That just requires space, and time.

Believe it or not, you have over-thought this problem. Additionally, your code style is off.

C# Code conventions always use braces for single-statement blocks, and the brace should open at the start of a new line. Code like:

> ```
> foreach (int i in fiboNums) { if (i % 2 == 0) sumEvenFibos += i; }
> ```

should be:

```
foreach (int i in fiboNums)
{
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        sumEvenFibos += i;
    }
}
```

As for the list, you don't need it:

```
int current = 1;
int previous = 0;
int sum = 0;
while (current <= 4000000)
{
    if ((current % 2) == 0)
    {
        sum += current;
    }
    int tmp = current + previous;
    previous = current;
    current = tmp;
}
```

Now, that whole thing should be put in its own function, and your main method with a parameter for the upper limit (4,000,000) and it becomes:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
    s.Start();

    int sumEvenFibos = GetFiboSum(4000000);

    s.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine(sumEvenFibos);
    Console.WriteLine(s.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

1. This:

   > ```
   > List<int> fiboNums = new List<int>();
   > GetFibos(ref fiboNums, 4000000);
   > ```

   looks like a C++-ism. In C# you have value types (`struct`) and reference types (`class`). `List<T>` is a class and thus passing it by `ref` doesn't gain you anything unless you want to replace the list object with a different one. If anything `GetFibos` should create the list, fill it and then return it.
2. `GetFibos` could be better named like `GetFibonacciNumbers`.
3. As @rolfl pointed out you don't actually need to store all the numbers - you can just generate them as a sequence with an enumerator and then do your processing on the resulting sequence:

   ```
   public IEnumerable<int> GetFibonacciNumbers(int max)
   {
       int current = 1;
       int previous = 0;
       while (current <= max)
       {
           yield return current;

           int tmp = current + previous;
           previous = current;
           current = tmp;
       }
   }
   ```

   Now you can combine this with some LINQ in order to calculate what you want:

   ```
   var sumOfAllEven = GetFibonacciNumbers(4000000).Where(n => n % 2 == 0).Sum();
   ```

Comment: @Hosch250: `List<T>` is a class and therefor a reference type. Reference types are always passed by reference (as the name indicates). This [article](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx) might be useful.